# TCP/IP socket receives random big number

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to make a client-server application in C++ using TCP/IP sockets, but when I am trying to receive data from the server the client receives a random big number, even if the server didn't send it.

On the server side I am first receiving client's user and after I am sending server's name and user's role:

```
std::string user = Communication_Protocol::recv_message(client_sock, logger);
client.set_user(user);

int user_role = database_manager.get_user_role(user);

Communication_Protocol::send_message(client_sock, this->name, logger);
Communication_Protocol::send_message(client_sock, std::to_string(user_role), logger);
```

On the client side I am first sending the user and after I am receiving server's name and user's role:

```
Communication_Protocol::send_message(client_sock, username, logger);
server_name = Communication_Protocol::recv_message(client_sock, logger);
role = std::stoi(Communication_Protocol::recv_message(client_sock, logger));
logger->add("ROLE=" + std::to_string(role));
```

The functions that are used from the communication protocol are:

```
    void send_message(SOCKET socket, std::string message, Logger *logger){
        std::string encapsulated_string = message;
        size_t total_bytes_sent = 0;
        size_t bytes_sent = 0;
        size_t size = encapsulated_string.size();
        send(socket, &size, sizeof(size), 0);
        while (total_bytes_sent < encapsulated_string.size()){
            std::string message_left = encapsulated_string.substr(bytes_sent);
            bytes_sent = send(socket, message_left.c_str(), sizeof(message_left.c_str()), 0);
            total_bytes_sent += bytes_sent;
            logger->add_network("SEND", encapsulated_string.substr(total_bytes_sent - bytes_sent, total_bytes_sent), "<RECIVER>");
            if(bytes_sent < 0){
                logger->add_error("MESSAGE NOT SENT");
                return;
            }
        }
                            
    }
    std::string get_message(SOCKET socket, size_t size){
        std::string message = "";
        char *recv_buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        size_t bytes_recived = 0;
        while (bytes_recived < size){
            memset(recv_buffer, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);
            size_t len = recv(socket, recv_buffer, size - bytes_recived, 0);
            if(len < 0){
                throw Socket_Error_Exception();
            }
            if(len == 0){
                throw Client_Down_Exception();
            }
            std::string recv_msg = std::string(recv_buffer); 
            message += recv_msg;
            bytes_recived += len;
        }
        delete recv_buffer;
        return message;        
    }
    std::string recv_message(SOCKET socket, Logger *logger){
        long message_size;
        std::string message = "";
        size_t recv_len = recv(socket, &message_size, sizeof(message_size), 0);
        if(message_size > 0){
            logger->add_network("RECV", "SIZE = " + std::to_string(message_size), "<SENDER>");
            message = get_message(socket, message_size);
            logger->add_network("RECV", "BODY = " + message, "<SENDER>");
        }
        
        return message;
    }
```

Server log:

```
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET RECV SIZE = 4 FROM <SENDER>
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET RECV BODY = USER FROM <SENDER>
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET SEND xxx TO <RECIVER>
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET SEND -1 TO <RECIVER>
```

Client log:

```
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET SEND USER TO <RECIVER>
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET RECV SIZE = 3 FROM <SENDER>
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET RECV BODY = xxx FROM <SENDER>
2020-8-16 16:51:45  NET RECV SIZE = 2199031643136 FROM <SENDER>
```

I've tried changing the order of the messages but only the first message from the server gets received normally, the second one gets a big number at size.
I thought it's a missing '\0' from a string or an overflow but I can't see a source of a bug like this.
I also considered that the problem is from receiving the user's role from the database but I've tried to put a sleep_for before receiving it and sending a hard coded integer but I get the same problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `send_message`, you are using `sizeof(message_left.c_str())` for the message length. That's the size of a pointer. You probably want `message_left.size()` instead:

```
bytes_sent = send(socket, message_left.c_str(), message_left.size(), 0);
```

Within `recv_message`, you're using `message_size` where you probably want to use the returned `recv_len` - also recv_len should be `ssize_t` because it can be -1:

```
    ssize_t recv_len = recv(socket, &message_size, sizeof(message_size), 0);
    if (recv_len > 0){
```

Within `get_message`, len should also be `ssize_t`:

```
ssize_t len = recv(socket, recv_buffer, size - bytes_recived, 0);
```